# SQL : ADD & MINUS based on Field type

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that look like below:

tableA

```
ID   |   BALANCE   |   ACTION_QTY   |   ACTION_TYPE |
----------------------------------------------------
1    |     0       |       3        |       ADD     |
2    |     0       |       2        |       DEDUCT  | 
3    |     0       |       6        |       ADD     |      
4    |     0       |       3        |       ADD     | 
5    |     0       |       1        |       DEDUCT  | 
6    |     0       |       7        |       ADD     | 
7    |     0       |       8        |       DEDUCT  | 
8    |     0       |       3        |       ADD     | 
9    |     0       |       7        |       DEDUCT  |  
10   |     0       |       9        |       ADD     |
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4723d/1)

How do i update the **BALANCE** field based on sum and deduct of **ACTION_TYPE** field and **ACTION_QTY** field

the result that i want is like below:

```
ID   |   BALANCE   |   ACTION_QTY   |   ACTION_TYPE |
----------------------------------------------------
1    |     3       |       3        |       ADD     |
2    |     1       |       2        |       DEDUCT  | 
3    |     7       |       6        |       ADD     |      
4    |     10      |       3        |       ADD     | 
5    |     9       |       1        |       DEDUCT  | 
6    |     16      |       7        |       ADD     | 
7    |     8       |       8        |       DEDUCT  | 
8    |     11      |       3        |       ADD     | 
9    |     4       |       7        |       DEDUCT  |  
10   |     13      |       9        |       ADD     |
```

any help would be great.

Comment: Why don't you store `ACTION_QTY` as +ve when `ACTION_TYPE=ADD` and -ve when `ACTION_TYPE=DEDUCT`, and then get rid of the `ACTION_TYPE` column?  Then the simple arithmetic summation of all records with `ID` less than or equal to the current record will yield the current balance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a variable to hold the cumulative amount:

```
SELECT ID, 
       @s := IF(ACTION_TYPE='ADD', @s + ACTION_QTY, @s - ACTION_QTY) AS BALANCE,
       ACTION_QTY,
       ACTION_TYPE
FROM tableA
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @s := 0) AS var
ORDER BY ID
```

The above query assumes that there are only two types of `ACTION_TYPE` values, namely `'ADD'` and `'DEDUCT'`. Hence, if `ACTION_TYPE` is not equal to `'ADD'`, then it is equal to `'DEDUCT'`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4723d/2)

Comment: thanks, it work perfect. how to add a group by addition field? to add and deduct by group only. let say PRODUCT_ID, i only want it to add and deduct by same product_id ?

Comment: @David That's a different requirement that involves a different set of data. It is generally not prefered to answer questions in comments. You can try posting a new question here in SO.