# SQL : ADD & MINUS based on Field type with GROUP BY condition

Tags: mysql, sql

This question is upgrade version [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806168/sql-add-minus-based-on-field-type/). The solution provided by Mr Giorgos Betsos are working fine. However i upgraded my requirement to be filter by PRODUCT_ID (using group by i assume). New table now look like this

```
ID   |   BALANCE   |   ACTION_QTY   |   ACTION_TYPE |   PRODUCT_ID   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------|
1    |     0       |       3        |       ADD     |       12       |
2    |     0       |       2        |       DEDUCT  |       12       |  
3    |     0       |       6        |       ADD     |       11       |      
4    |     0       |       3        |       ADD     |       11       | 
5    |     0       |       1        |       DEDUCT  |       12       | 
6    |     0       |       7        |       ADD     |       15       | 
7    |     0       |       1        |       DEDUCT  |       15       | 
8    |     0       |       3        |       ADD     |       15       | 
9    |     0       |       7        |       DEDUCT  |       11       |  
10   |     0       |       9        |       ADD     |       12       |
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2ceae6/2)

How do i do the add/minus to **BALANCE** field based on **PRODUCT_ID** and order by **ID**? @Giorgos Betsos's SQL:

```
SELECT ID, 
       @s := IF(ACTION_TYPE='ADD', @s + ACTION_QTY, @s - ACTION_QTY) AS BALANCE,
       ACTION_QTY,
       ACTION_TYPE
FROM tableA
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @s := 0) AS var
ORDER BY ID
```

i tried to add GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID, but the result isnt correct.

Result that i want is like below:

```
ID   |   BALANCE   |   ACTION_QTY   |   ACTION_TYPE |   PRODUCT_ID   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------|
1    |     3       |       3        |       ADD     |       12       |
2    |     1       |       2        |       DEDUCT  |       12       |  
3    |     6       |       6        |       ADD     |       11       |      
4    |     9       |       3        |       ADD     |       11       | 
5    |     0       |       1        |       DEDUCT  |       12       | 
6    |     7       |       7        |       ADD     |       15       | 
7    |     6       |       1        |       DEDUCT  |       15       | 
8    |     9       |       3        |       ADD     |       15       | 
9    |     2       |       7        |       DEDUCT  |       11       |  
10   |     9       |       9        |       ADD     |       12       |
```

Please Help Me,
Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `CASE EXPRESSION` inside a correlated query :

```
SELECT s.id,
       (SELECT sum(CASE WHEN t.action_type = 'ADD' THEN t.action_qty ELSE -1*t.action_qty END)
        FROM (YourQuery) t
        WHERE t.id <= s.id and t.product_id = s.product_id),
       s.action_qty,s.action_type,s.product_id
FROM (YourQuery) s
ORDER BY s.id
```

The case will determine if to sum the value, or to sum the `value*-1` by the value in `action_type` column.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i am not sure if i understand it correct. So you only want to sum the ACTION_QTY over the field ACTION_TYPE ? try like this:

```
SELECT ID,
       SUM (
         IF(ACTION_TYPE='ADD', ACTION_QTY,  -1 * ACTION_QTY)
       ) AS BALANCE,
       ACTION_QTY,
       ACTION_TYPE
FROM tableA
GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID
ORDER BY PRODUCT_ID;
```

**sample

**Create the table**

```
MariaDB [bb]> CREATE TABLE tableA
    -> (`ID` int, `BALANCE` decimal(10,4), `ACTION_QTY` decimal(10,4), `ACTION_TYPE` varchar(100), `PRODUCT_ID` int(20))
    -> ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.41 sec)

MariaDB [bb]>
MariaDB [bb]> INSERT INTO tableA
    -> (`ID`, `BALANCE`, `ACTION_QTY`, `ACTION_TYPE`, `PRODUCT_ID`)
    -> VALUES
    -> (1, '0.00', '3', 'ADD', '12'),
    ->     (2, '0.00', '2', 'DEDUCT', '12'),
    ->     (3, '0.00', '6', 'ADD', '11'),
    ->     (4, '0.00', '3', 'ADD', '11'),
    ->     (5, '0.00', '1', 'DEDUCT', '12'),
    ->     (6, '0.00', '7', 'ADD', '15'),
    ->     (7, '0.00', '8', 'DEDUCT', '15'),
    ->     (8, '0.00', '3', 'ADD', '15'),
    ->     (9, '0.00', '7', 'DEDUCT', '11'),
    ->     (10,'0.00', '9', 'ADD', '12')
    -> ;
Query OK, 10 rows affected (0.08 sec)
Records: 10  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

**run the query**

```
MariaDB [bb]> SELECT ID,
    ->        SUM(
    ->          IF(ACTION_TYPE='ADD', ACTION_QTY,  -1 * ACTION_QTY)
    ->        ) AS BALANCE,
    ->        ACTION_QTY,
    ->        ACTION_TYPE
    -> FROM tableA
    -> GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID
    -> ORDER BY PRODUCT_ID;
+------+---------+------------+-------------+
| ID   | BALANCE | ACTION_QTY | ACTION_TYPE |
+------+---------+------------+-------------+
|    3 |  2.0000 |     6.0000 | ADD         |
|    1 |  9.0000 |     3.0000 | ADD         |
|    6 |  2.0000 |     7.0000 | ADD         |
+------+---------+------------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.03 sec)

MariaDB [bb]>
```

Comment: This will return a single record.

Comment: @sagi - ups, my mistake, i not copy all. i have change my answer

Comment: Now the sum won't be cumulative sum.

Comment: @sagi - can you try again

Comment: Now you will have only 1 record per product, he doesn't want that. You have to use the query twice.